# Python: pip installing requests for older version: 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip, python-requests

I'm trying to interface with an API using a python program that only works in 2.7 and not in 3.4 which is also installed on my machine.  However, one of my program's dependencies is the `requests` module.  I have `requests` available in my 3.4 environment, but in 2.7 `import requests` results in:

```
import error: no such module named requests
```

Many Stack Overflow Q&A's have reccomended installing requests for 2.7 using: `pip2.7 install requests`, but apparently I don't have `pip2.7` because that results in:

```
'pip2.7' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

**Question**: How can I get pip2.7 instead of my default pip?  Is it a seperate version of pip or do I just need to tell my current version I'm trying to install for version 2.7 not 2.4?

**Note:** The suggested solution to use `easy_install-2.7 -U pip` to install pip2.7 doesn't run on my Windows7 maching, the command propmt prints : `easy_instal-2.7 is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: afaik its a different version of setuptools.

Comment: did you install pip using `get-pip.py` with `python 2.7` or how did you install? If not save this file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py and make sure you use python2.7 to install.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Apparently pip was installed by directly downloading a windows binary

Comment: using just pip uses python 3.4?

Comment: it would seem that way since `pip install requests` says the module is already installed, which it is for the 3.4 version.  Thanks for the link I'll try that

Comment: did you install the binary from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default 3.4 won't create the plain `pip` command but it can be enabled with an option which is presumably what has been done in your case. Since there are other names for the Python 3 `pip` you can safely overwrite it by installing the 2.7 `pip` on top of it with `easy_install`.

Since this is Windows, your Python binaries are kept in isolated directories so you should just ensure that the 2.7 directory is first in the path variable. Look in the `<python root 2.7>\Scripts` directory to see if you have an `easy_install` already. If not you need to install setuptools.

Comment: Interesting, I looked in the Scripts folder like you said and I see both `easy_install-2.7` scripts and `pip2.7` scripts, yet when I called either of those from the command prompt it had no idea what I was referring to

Comment: You need to put that directory into your path or use the full path to run those programs from the command line. Look in Control Panel|System|Advanced system settings|Environment variables|System variables.